# How to convert ant multirootfileset to standard fileset?

Tags: java, ant

Is there a way to convert Ant's `multirootfileset` (since 1.9.4) to a standard fileset?

I have some older tasks that don't work with a `multirootfileset`, but I haven't found an easy way to convert it. The challenge seems to be converting absolute paths to relative paths to play nicely in a `fileset`. It is a challenge as I don't easily know a common parent in the directory hierarchy based on our build script usage - short of possibly going up to the drive level.

Is there a way to update paths from absolute to relative based on some arbitrary path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this using [`<pathtofileset>` from ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/pathtofileset.html). Here is my solution:

```
<path id="my.path">
    <multirootfileset refid="original.fileset" />
</path>

<contrib:pathtofileset name="new.fileset" pathrefid="my.path" dir="${basedir}" />
```